# does swift's string type conform to collection protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, string, collections, protocols

In the swift programming language book, it states

> You can use the startIndex and endIndex properties and the
>   index(before:), index(after:), and index(_:offsetBy:) methods on any
>   type that conforms to the Collection protocol. This includes String,
>   as shown here, as well as collection types such as Array, Dictionary,
>   and Set.

However, I have checked the apple documentation on swift's string api, which does not indicate that `String` type conform to `Collection` protocol

[image]

I must be missing something here, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Swift 2, `String` does not conform to `Collection`, only its various "views"
like `characters`, `utf8`, `utf16` or `unicodeScalars`.

(This might again change in the future, compare 
[String should be a Collection of Characters Again](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md#string-should-be-a-collection-of-characters-again) in
[String Processing For Swift 4](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/StringManifesto.md).)

It has `startIndex` and `endIndex` properties and `index` methods though, these
are forwarded to the `characters` view, as can be seen in 
the source code
[StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringRangeReplaceableCollection.swift.gyb#L16):

```
extension String {
  /// The index type for subscripting a string.
  public typealias Index = CharacterView.Index


  // ...

  /// The position of the first character in a nonempty string.
  ///
  /// In an empty string, `startIndex` is equal to `endIndex`.
  public var startIndex: Index { return characters.startIndex }


  /// A string's "past the end" position---that is, the position one greater
  /// than the last valid subscript argument.
  ///
  /// In an empty string, `endIndex` is equal to `startIndex`.
  public var endIndex: Index { return characters.endIndex }

  /// Returns the position immediately after the given index.
  ///
  /// - Parameter i: A valid index of the collection. `i` must be less than
  ///   `endIndex`.
  /// - Returns: The index value immediately after `i`.
  public func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
    return characters.index(after: i)
  }


  // ...
}
```

Comment: hi Martin! nice to see you again, hoping you are having a good day :)

Comment: your answer never stop amazes me! It is so complete and informed! Do you mind if I ask what is the method you use to look for resources and to resolve a problem? Cause if Im by myself, it would take me days to find those relevant resources.

Answer (score 1):

**Strings** are collections again. This means you can reverse them, loop over them character-by-character, map() and flatMap() them, and more. For example:

let quote = "It is a truth universally acknowledged that new Swift versions bring new features."
let reversed = quote.reversed()

for letter in quote {
print(letter)
}
This change was introduced as part of a broad set of amendments called the String Manifesto.